# What do we mean by 'resonance frequency' of a system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, frequency, oscillators, resonance, vibrations

Whenever we talk about oscillations, we generally take the term 'resonant frequency' for granted, but I don't understand what this frequency depends on.
For example, if we talk about a freely suspended pendulum, the interchange of kinetic and potential energy gives rise to oscillations, but these definitions of resonant frequency change from system to system.

Is there anything similar to all these oscillating systems and in particular what factors affect the resonance frequency of a system. Also, why do we assume that all objects have a resonant frequency in the first place?

Comment: " why do we assume that all objects have a resonant frequency" - we shouldn't as they don't, particularly composite materials or irregularly shaped ones. You'll find multi-modal resonances come into play.

Answer (score 1):

A resonant frequency is one where energy at that frequency easily enters or leaves the system, while energy at other frequencies does not easily enter or leave the system.

There is no one fixed set of parameters that determine the resonance frequency for all systems. For vibrational modes stiffness and mass will be important, for pendulums length and mass are important, for circuits capacitance and inductance are important, etc.

It is not assumed that all systems have a resonance. In fact, it is often an important matter of engineering to remove unwanted resonances from a design.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the pendulum you reference in your question, the equation of motion is:

$$mL^2\ddot \theta + mgL \sin{\theta} = 0 $$

It's not a linear system, and is difficult to solve...as are most things encounter in engineering and science.

However, for small oscillations about equilibrium you can Taylor expand the sine function to get:

$$\ddot \theta + \frac g L\theta = 0 $$

which is the ubiquitous simple harmonic oscillator.

The solution looks like $e^{i\omega_0 t}$ where the frequency is:

$$ \omega_0 = \sqrt{\frac g L}$$

You can see that the frequency is related to the ratio of the restoring force $mgL$ and the inertia $mL^2$. Any other oscillator (e.g. RCL circuit) will have analogous terms. Also: many, if not most, systems can be treated as a simple harmonic oscillator for small deviations from equilibrium.

If you drive the above system with a force at frequency $\omega$, it will gain infinite energy only if $\omega' = \omega_0$, zero otherwise.

In real systems, there is damping, which broadens the (now finite) frequency response. If it is too broad (over damped), the system may not look like a resonant system at all. Moreover, if it's multidimensional, one must consider coupling of the various oscillators.